# Getting req.user.following undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm creating social network app with MERN. I have implemented followers and following, and now i'm trying to get the list of posts of only users that i'm following. So, if I console.log my req.user I only get the 'id' and 'iat', but i need more information of a user such as following array.

here is what i have:
auth.js middlware:

```
const config = require('config')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

function auth(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token')

    // check for token
    if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Unauthorized token' })

    try {
        // verify token
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'))

        // add user from payload
        req.user = decoded
        console.log('---',decoded)
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid' })
    }
}

module.exports = auth
```

auth.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const config = require('config')

const User = require('../models/User')
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')

// @route   POST /api/auth
// @desc    Login user
// @access  Public

router.post('/', (req, res) => {

    const { email, password } = req.body

    // filed validation
    if (!email || !password) res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Fields cannot be empty.' })

    // Check if user is registered
    User
        .findOne({ email })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) res.status(400).json({ msg: `User doesn't exist.` })
            //console.log(user)
            // validate password
            bcrypt
                .compare(password, user.password)
                .then(isMatch => {
                    if (!isMatch) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Invalid password' })

                    // if password matches, send token and user
                    jwt.sign(
                        { id: user.id },
                        config.get('jwtSecret'),
                        (err, token) => {
                            if (err) throw err

                            res.json({
                                token,
                                user: {
                                    id: user.id,
                                    email: user.email,
                                    first_name: user.first_name,
                                    last_name: user.last_name,
                                    registration_date: user.registration_date,
                                    profile_image: user.profile_image,
                                    user_bio: user. user_bio,
                                    followers: user.followers,
                                    following: user.following
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    )
                })
        })

})
```

and this is my console log

```
 Server started at port 5000
[0] --- { id: '5efccfb13224e1489439bcfd', iat: 1593626545 }
[0] * { id: '5efccfb13224e1489439bcfd', iat: 1593626545 }
```

EDIT:

```
// @route   GET /api/posts/subscribedPost
// @desc    get all subscribed post
// @access  Private

router.get('/subscribedPost', auth, (req, res) => {
    console.log('*',req.user)     // not working correctly, have only id and iat
    Post
        .find({userID: req.user.id})
        .populate('userID', 'first_name last_name profile_image _id')
        .sort({ registration_date: -1 })
        .then(post => res.json(post))
        .catch(err => res.json(err))
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are signing your JWT token with `id` only, so when u decode it you will only get `id`

```
jwt.sign({ id: user.id },config.get('jwtSecret'),(err, token) =>{})
```

Here you are just passing `id`, you can pass your whole `user` object to get all the data

```
jwt.sign(user.toJSON(),config.get('jwtSecret'),(err, token) =>{})
```

**PS- YOU MIGHT NOT WANT TO PASS YOUR WHOLE `USER`, JUST DID IT FOR DEMO**

You can customize to what values you want.

Comment: yeah, but now i get the correct result only if user logs in, but i need in any time

Comment: I'm not sure what do u mean? Can u elaborate

Comment: if i log in, i get the correct response with whole user and i have access to for example req.user.following and that is great, but if i make some other request, for example `@route GET /api/posts/subscribedPost` and if i console log req.user i get only its 'id' and 'iat'

Comment: i made EDIT so you can see my route where i'm trying to get whole user, not only id

Comment: ok, i get something now, but it works only if user logs in, for example: user started to follow another user and he should see its posts but he doesn't, he sees it only if he logs in again, and than data is refreshed, how to fix this?

Comment: @Marina is it because u need to send a refresh request after user starts following?

Comment: I'm not sure how your `React` code looks like but i'm assuming u are using `useEffect` hook, if so  you can dependency on `user`, so whenever user value changes it will make a request.

Comment: it's not about refreshing the page, i tried that, i need to log in  again, even though i am logged in, to see new results, why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get user data DB in auth middleware and then add it to req.user. So if there are any changes to the user you get updated user data.

eg:

```
function auth(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token')

    // check for token
    if (!token) return res.status(401).json({ msg: 'Unauthorized token' })

    try {
        // verify token
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, config.get('jwtSecret'))

        // get the user from DB

        const user = User.findById(decoded.id) //only populate fields which are required

        req.user = user
        console.log('---',decoded)
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Token is not valid' })
    }
}
```

Comment: still my console.log(req.user.following) is undefined, why?

Comment: and console.log(req.user) gives me Post and not User schema